# How can I implement a text search in node.js using a Postgres database?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, search, express, search-engine

I want to add search functionality to an expressjs node application using Postgres as my database.
I know how to do the filtering I'll need by date and some other column of finite values, but I don't know how to do a text search on a specific column. 
Given a string "chair", should my search algorithm return results with text like "my armchair", or "my chair"?

Maybe this question is so simple I'm just overlooking something.
Thanks!

Comment: If you don't want to use an external search engine (Solr, ElasticSearch, ...) you can use Postgres' built-in full-text search: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-textsearch.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <colume> ~* '\ychair\y'
```

Where `\y` denotes [the beginning/end of words](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#POSIX-CONSTRAINT-ESCAPES-TABLE)

Comment: I didn't get that to work, but `SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE <column> ~* 'chair'` worked for me, including rows containing something like "chairleg". I don't understand the purpose of `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`

Comment: Edited. @Shakeel Could you try \y?

Comment: Yeah that didn't work either. But I think it works fine as I noted in my previous comment. Thanks though!